When do smooth equations define a manifold?
Suppose you have some $C^\infty$ functions of $N$ variables $f_k(x_1, \dots, x_N)$ for $k=1, \dots, M <N$, and you want to consider the set
$$\mathcal{M} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N \, : \,f_k(x_1, \dots, x_N) = 0, \, \forall k=1, \dots, M \} $$
I am interested in what circumstances this defines a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$. I already know of a partial answer. If the differentials $d f_k(x_1, \dots, x_N)$ are linearly independent at some point in $\mathcal{M}$ then one can use the implicit function theorem to define a local inverse and so $\mathcal{M}$ is a submanifold at that point. My question is, suppose there are some "singular" points where the differentials are not linearly independent. If I'm not mistaken, this tends to happen at branch points. It would seem that the dimension of the manifold cannot change discontinuously at these points, so I would expect (?) that $\mathcal{M}$ is still a manifold at these points, and so there ought to be some "better" coordinates where the manifold structure can be seen. Is this correct and how can one find such coordinates?
EDIT: OK so I see from the comments that the answer to my question is no, they do not define a manifold, since there may be "cusps." However I am interested studying the behaviour of the set $\mathcal{M}$ in a neighbourhood of the "singular" points. What theory helps me study this? e.g. is this the topic of Morse Theory or should I look elsewhere? Catastrophe theory perhaps? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Start by working out some examples, for instance, $xy=0$ or $x^2=y^3$...

It is actually much worse than you think and the level set could be any closed subset, say, the Cantor set. Yes, Morse theory will tell you the answer in the case of nondegenerate critical points of a single function. But you have to narrow down the focus of your question to make it answerable.

The situation is indeed quite complicated. For example, consider the special case where, in a neighborhood of a singular point, there exist coordinates in which the functions $f_k$ are all polynomials. Your question then becomes one in real algebraic geometry. If you dig into that, you'll see that no answer is known. An even more special case is when the functions can be written as complex polynomials. The question is now one in complex algebraic geometry. Much more is known here, but there is no complete answer.
